# Cars with single fuel type how retrieve tank level to dashboard?

Tags: obd-ii, fuel-consumption, fuel-tank, pid

I see that BiFuel cars had fuel level and type readable from ECU by using pid 0151 and 012F.

Cars with monofuel don't have this pids sensors, so how the dashboard retrive the fuel level?
Maybe the sensor is not connected to ECU but directly to dashboard?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OBD-II Fuel type and level of Monofuel Cars](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/50231/obd-ii-fuel-type-and-level-of-monofuel-cars)

Comment: It's mine that post, and it's different the question :)

Comment: They are both about fuel level....

Comment: yes but different problem...two different problems.
The first talk about pid 7F 01 22 and this how dashboard of car retrieve fuel level