# Android OBD2 Fuel

Tags: obd-ii

Currently I'm developing an Android app that uses an OBD2 ELM327 device to read some data from the car, so I could use it in my application. Now, when I want to read the fuel, fuel consumption or something else concerned the fuel, I receive "NO DATA" from the OBD. Does anybody have any experience with this? I tried it on a BMW, Mercedes and Kia.

Would be appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Are you able to pull other PIDs from the reader? You are sure you have a connection and the device is running properly? If you're not sure, you can use a free app like Torque Lite to pull up information for confirmation. There is a selection within Torque to give you fuel information if the vehicle provides it to you, so you can make sure everything with the ELM327 device is working correctly.

Comment: I do have a connection and I am able to pull other PIDs, only the PIDs about fuel returns "NO DATA".

Comment: Have a look at these two questions : https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/50391/cars-with-single-fuel-type-how-retrieve-tank-level-to-dashboard  AND  https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/50231/obd-ii-fuel-type-and-level-of-monofuel-cars

Comment: Have you tried to pull PIDs 00, 20, 40, 60, 80 to see if the vehicle reports that it is able to answer the PIDs you want to pull?